# Timesat image output to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, modis, timesat

I processed MODIS MOD13Q1 NDVI times series (from 2000 to 2015) in Timesat. I specifically extracted start of season data and for each year (growth season) I was able to produce an image showing the SOS across my study area using the seas2img function. I was able to save these images as pictures but fail to understand how these images can be exported in a format that I will be able to use in ArcMAP in order to do further analyses. Please advise if this is at all possible and what process I need to follow to get it done.

Comment: In what environment/software do run the script you provided here?

Comment: Please post it this type of questions in comment section of the original question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create the header file (*.hdr) for each TIMESAT binary output. You can follow my hdr file below.

```
ENVI
description = {C:\timesat32\compiled\Win64\indonesia_all_rice_2000_2001_eos_s1}
samples = 21863
lines = 7910
bands = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 2
interleave = bsq
byte order = 0
map info = {Geographic Lat/Lon, 1, 1, 95.1525139304, 5.63277950899, 0.00209129, 0.00209129, WGS-84}
coordinate system string = {GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137, 298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["DEGREE",0.017453292519943295]]}
band names = {
Band 1}
```

And please make sure you are modified some information:

1. Adjust the description name
2. You need to replace the image dimension
   (samples and lines) with yours. To get it you can use

> gdalinfo yourfile.bil

3. You must know the top-left coordinate and the pixel
   size of your image, and replace "95.1525139304, 5.63277950899,
   0.00209129, 0.00209129" with your data.
4. If necessary you could also change the coordinate system.

After you got your hdr file, you can convert to GeoTIF using gdal

> gdal_translate -of GTiff startofseason startofseason.tif

or if you want to convert all the data in the directory

> for i in `find . -type f ! -name "*.hdr"`; do gdal_translate -of GTiff
>   $i $i.tif; done

Comment: This was asked above, but what software is this script run in?

Comment: @Beck you need to install GDAL to run above script. I am using Mac, if you are using Windows then you need to adjust few syntax in last script. But if you use Windows Subsystem for Linux, you are good.

Comment: Which library do you load for it? (I'm quite new to coding, and a first timer for GDAL.) As well, by last script, do you mean `find . -type f ! -name "*.hdr"`?

Comment: There is no additional library, just one-liner script is enough. I used last script to batch convert lot of Timesat binary output files in a folder. If I just type `for i in *.hdr; do` will not work, as gdal will can’t read/convert the header file.

Comment: How did you build this? Did you download a build from Github?

Comment: @Beck are you referring to GDAL? If yes, I install gdal on my Mac via Homebrew `brew install gdal`. In my windows machine, I prefer install gdal using Anaconda `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

Comment: Noted! I've installed gdal with Anaconda. However, I'm running into an issue that when I enter my file for `gdal_translate -of GTiff startofseason startofseason.tif` it returns the error "not recognized as a supported file format." I also noticed that you specify `.bil` as the file format, but my TIMESAT output does not have any extension. Did you have to convert your TIMESAT output to an accepted format for gdal?

Comment: @Beck .bil is the input for running timesat. I used .bil file to get the bounding box of the file. Have you create startofseason.hdr?

Comment: I made the .hdr file for the output of seas2img, which doesn't have a file extension. My data are tiffs that I converted into binary .rst format, so I got my bounding box from the tiffs. Is this approach correct?

Comment: @Beck yes. If it still fails, please upload to cloud the example output and input (rst/tiff is fine). Send me the link.

Comment: Here is a link to a Google Drive containing the files: [link] https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZEAQwC-nci0AYT1Hp-_Zu5XN9CkjjwPy?usp=sharing Please let me know if it works and if you need any additional information. Thank you so much for all of your help so far!

Comment: @Beck thanks, I have checked and I think there’s something wrong with your data. My gdal couldn’t recognize all rst and tif files. Tried to open using qgis, but failed. Could you open it in qgis? Then send me the screenshot of information tab in layer properties.

Comment: I just recheck again, seems your .hdr filename is different, then I renamed into 1315sos_season1.hdr and do `gdal_translate -of GTiff 1315sos_season1 1315sos_season1.tif` its worked and I assume your header file content is correct.

Comment: This worked!! I had to edit the data type and byte order, but it processed and I have the desired output! Thank you so much for your help; I appreciate it more than I can express.

Comment: Well done @Beck

Comment: @Beck btw running timesat with only 1 year data is not good idea if you try to get the full season within a year. For example to get  a full year season for 2019, I prefer to use data from Jul 2018 to Jun 2020. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: I've duplicated each year's data so it is like two years are being run. For example, if I'm running 2013, I'll take the data from January-June and add it to the end, and the data from July-December gets added to the beginning. Is this still inadvisable?

Comment: @Beck cool, it’s ok.