# How to extract phenology metrics from every singe pixel in an image with TIMESAT

Tags: timesat

I want to extract phenology metrics of every pixel in an image. I have 92 MODIS images (4 years and 23 images per year) of a zone, and I want to extract the metrics data (as a text or ASCII file) to use it in a model to map a crop in that zone.

I used .tif images but had some problems to load the image correctly so I transformed them to ENVI (with QGIS), the image load correctly in TSM_imageview but I can not process the list of the time series in TSM_imageview neither in TSM_GUI, I tried using other format (IDRISI, .img) but it does not work.

When I load the image list in TSM_imageview I only receive a message in the command window:

```
   Error using dataread
   Trouble reading integer from file (row 1, field 1) ==> ÿ_9

   Error in strread (line 48)


   Error in openfilelist

   Error using waitforallfiguresclosed (line 20)
   Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Then when I tried to load the list in TSM_GUI, I write the informations (number of rows and columns, years) and the number of images per year (that supposed to load automatically) disappears, when I write it manually the number of years disappears.

I do not know what happens, anyone can give me an advice?

[image: picture of the problem with TM_imageview and TSM_GUI]

Comment: Hi I frequently used TIMESAT to monitor rice cultivation and harvest using mod13q1. Could you post example one of your RST data?

Comment: Hello, I already manage to solve the problem, I did the list of files in R first and then TIMESAT could read the list.

Comment: However, I want to know if it is possible to extract as output the phenology metrics from TIMESAT as a ASCII file?

Comment: From my understanding, possible but not direct. The seasonality metric output is in binary, you need to create a header file then you can convert it to GeoTIFF. From there is easy to make an ascii file. You can follow my answer in other thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/252507/97103

Comment: @FernandoTroyaAndrade Yes, you can extract the phenology metrices. First you create NDVI time-series curve then apply filtering method you want and set NDVI start and end value, you'll get the seasonality parameter which you can easily write to text file.